# On click drop down input: unable to goto top item on click

Tags: jquery, html

I've created a drop down input that when you click on the items it goes to the page.

```
<form id="work" action="" method="post">
    <select id="work-list" class="sub-topics" name="work">
    <?php $id = get_the_ID();
    $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => $id, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order')); 
    foreach($pages as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    $fields = get_fields(); ?>
        <option class="work-dropdown" value="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></option>    
    <?php } wp_reset_query(); ?> 
    </select>           
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
   $('select[name="work"]').change(function(){
        window.location = $(this).val();
    })
});
</script>
```

At the moment the top page is the drop down has a tick next to it so when clicking it, it doesn't goto the page. If you click the second item then that works fine, it's just it think the top item is selected.

How can I make the top item clickable like the rest?

**If possible I want to avoid putting in a selection at the top like "click here to choose a page" or anything along those lines.**

Comment: Rob can you paste the HTML generated for the dropdown from the above wordpress code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add the 1st item item to the drop-down list as `click below to choose a page to visit`

Comment: "If possible I want to avoid putting in a selection at the top like "click here to choose a page" or anything along those lines." :D

Comment: @tymeJV you are open for better solution you can make a edit .

Comment: As mentioned by @thmejv, not what I want.

Comment: Might be the only way though, the reason the `change` event doesn't fire is because you never actually change anything. I would make a default option like this `<option selected disabled>Choose</option>` -- that way, once the user clicks it, they HAVE to choose another option since the default is disabled.

Comment: @tymeJV yeah this is the only option .

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
window.location.href = $(this).val();
```

instead of

```
window.location = $(this).val();
```

Comment: @SKV Gave that a go but no luck when clicking on the top page.